# Jboss order loading problem

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, deployment, jcr

Imagine we have 2 wars to deploy. First war should load some data into JCR repository, or any other storage. Second war uses data that is loaded by first war in storage.

Now we have situation when first war is successfully deployed, but it is in the middle of initialization process(loading data). Second war is starting to deploy. So have have an error.

Is there any config where we can define time after which second war should be deployed. I mean jboss config.

I guess the problem is clear. Now in production we have one war (Apache sling) that deploy JCR schema(bundle) into repository, and second war starts working with it.

Maybe somebody had similar issue and could help me?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be for the second war to contain a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) whose [contextInitialized()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method waits until the first war is ready for use.